# Foreign-data wrapper "postgres_fdw" does not exist (even if it does)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10, foreign-data-wrapper

Using PostgreSQL 10.10, from superuser `postgres`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw TO my_user;
```

Then when doing the following from `my_user`:

```
CREATE SERVER my_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (...);
```

This error message is displayed:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  foreign-data wrapper "postgres_fdw" does not exist
```

Here is the list of currently active foreign data wrappers (from psql):

```
postgres=# \dew
                      List of foreign-data wrappers
     Name     |  Owner   |       Handler        |       Validator
--------------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 postgres_fdw | postgres | postgres_fdw_handler | postgres_fdw_validator
(1 row)
```

How comes, even after having been granted `USAGE`, the user `my_user` is still not able to see/use postgres_fdw foreign data wrapper, as if the latter didn't exist? Are there more steps necessary?

Comment: I suspect that you are doing something different from what you say you are doing, else your second statement would fail.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you were right, I tried creating the wrapper first and then installed the extension. Starting again from a fresh installation and not creating the wrapper myself (only installing the extension) leads to the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Then you must be running the statements in different databases.

Comment: ah!!! that must be it! I was naively assuming that foreign data wrappers were db-agnostic — EDIT: that was effectively it, thanks for your help. You might make it an answer which I'll accept for future folks who get this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since foreign data wrappers do not live in a schema, the only explanation would be that `CREATE EXTENSION` and `CREATE SERVER` were run in different databases (foreign data wrappers are not “global objects”). YOu have to run these statements in the same database.

By the way, the explicit `CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` would result in an error, since a foreign data wrapper of that name is already created by the extension.